# How can I validate data before insert/update with SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, ddl

I have a table defined like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ObjectRelationClauses]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [RelationId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [OperatorType] NVARCHAR(3) NOT NULL, 
    [LocalPropertyId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [ForeignPropertyId] INT NULL, 
    [ForeignValue] VARCHAR(255) NULL, 
    [ParentClauseId] INT NULL
)
```

I need to be able to raise an error if the value of both `ForeignPropertyId` and `ForeignValue` columns both `null`, otherwise I want to perform the operation.

Here is what I tried

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_ObjectRelationClauses]
    ON [dbo].[ObjectRelationClauses]
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NoCount ON
        IF(ForeignPropertyId IS NULL AND ForeignValue IS NULL)
        BEGIN
           RAISERROR('Either ForeignPropertyId or ForeignValue must be provided to perform this action!')
        END

    END
```

but this gives me a syntax error. Perhaps, the way I am using `RAISERROR` is wrong.

How can I correctly add a trigger to validate the data on `INSERT` and `UPDATE`?

Comment: use error severity or error number inside [raiserror function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497(v=sql.105).aspx) OR write a check constraint instead of the trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for a check constraint, not a trigger:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ObjectRelationClauses]
ADD CONSTRAINT foreign_chk CHECK 
([ForeignPropertyId] IS NOT NULL OR [ForeignValue] IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Very cool! It is time for me to google the different between a trigger and a constraint. I will accept your answer when time permits.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a constraint.  However, if you are inserting multiple rows, then the constraint will prevent *any* rows from being inserted.  To get around this, you can use an `instead of` trigger.

But, it might be easier simply to do:

```
insert into ObjectRelationClauses(. . .)
    select . . .
    from . . .
    where ForeignPropertyId is not null or ForeignValue is not null;
```

If you insert one row at a time, then the `constraint` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Because the SQL server dont know which record you are referring as per ForeignPropertyId and ForeignValue.

1) You should have taken use of the MAGIC TABLE. inserted.ForeignPropertyId is NULL AND inserted.ForeignValue is NULL.

2) You can use Instead Of trigger, not the For/After trigger.

If you are not that comfortable with trigger, my advice is not to use them too much. It will give you headache in the future.

Answer (score 0):

RAISERROR Required Levels of Severity & State . Please use this query

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_ObjectRelationClauses]
ON [dbo].[ObjectRelationClauses]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NoCount ON;
    DECLARE @ForeignPropertyId INT ,@ForeignValue varchar(255)
     Select @ForeignPropertyId=  i.ForeignPropertyId, @ForeignValue = i.ForeignValue from Inserted i
    IF(@ForeignPropertyId IS NULL AND @ForeignValue IS NULL)
    BEGIN
       RAISERROR ('Either ForeignPropertyId or ForeignValue must be provided to perform this action!',16,1)
    END

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you USE SQL `NOT NULL` Constraint ?

The NOT NULL constraint enforces a column to NOT accept NULL values.

You can alter your existing column by referring below snippet.

```
ALTER TABLE [Table] ALTER COLUMN [Column] INTEGER NOT NULL;
```